# Can't access AWS ec2 instance behind elastic load balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I've been following [lynda.com's AWS essential training](http://www.lynda.com/AWS-tutorials/Amazon-Web-Services-Essential-Training/163929-2.html) and I've successfully set up an EC2 instance but when I try to put it behind a load balancer I can not access it through the ELB's public DNS.

On the AWS Load Balancer console it says the status of my instance is OutOfService.  As per the tutorial I set up the a health check for the load balancer with a path of `/heartbeat.php`.

I also have **two security groups** set up.  The first one is named *Load Balancer - Prod* which allows HTTP traffic on port `80` in from anyone.  My Load balancer belongs to this security group. Additionally I have a security group called *Web Tier - Prod* which only allows HTTP traffic on port `80` from the *Load Balancer - Prod* security group and my own IP, SSH on my IP and MYSQL traffic from itself, the *Web Tier - Prod* security group.

I can access the instance with it's own public DNS and I can SSH into it, I just can't access it via the load balancers public DNS.

When I ssh into it and chack the NGINX access logs, I see this logged many times.

```
172.??.??.?? - - [26/Aug/2015:16:43:46 +0000] "GET /heartbeat.php HTTP/1.1" 401 203 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
```

I should be seeing a 200 status code instead of 401 203 I guess.  I tried changing permissions on `/var/www/` to 777 recursively as a test but that made no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the status check is returning a 401, AWS sees the instance as unhealthy and takes it out of the ELB. Since you have no healthy instances, the ELB is down.

Note that AWS accesses `/heartbeat.php` via IP, **not via DNS name**. Check the response using `curl -I http://<your instance IP>/heartbeat.php` and adjust your server config if it's not being served by the default virtualhost.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I forgot I had HTTP Auth on, using the curl command helped me spot it thanks :)